# face_recognition python flask not processing passed image

Tags: python, flask, image-processing, face-recognition, flask-restful

I have made a Flask API and I want to pass an image from my Flutter app to the API POST endpoint. I successfully transfer the image, but when I want to use it in

```
  first_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image_from_post_request or down below image1)
```

it just gives me errors!

When I try this function with an image that is saved locally it works. For Example:

```
  first_image = face_recognition.load_image_file('./img/mj.png')
```

I have tried saving that post image locally and then parsing it, but it doesn't work. I am a beginner with this, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You

My Code:

```
@app.route('/compare', methods=['POST'])
  def compare():
  image1 = request.files['face1']
  image2 = request.files['face2']

  first_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image1)
  first_image_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(first_image)[0]


  unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image2)
  second_image_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

  results = face_recognition.compare_faces([first_image_encoding], second_image_encoding)

  if results[0]:
      print('These images are same')
      return jsonify({'response' : 'These images are same'})
  else: 
      print('These images are not same')
      return jsonify({'response' : 'These images are not same'})
```

ERROR:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2020 00:07:05] "POST /compare HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bilal/.local/share/virtualenvs/face_reck_api-svbO_hqN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/bilal/.local/share/virtualenvs/face_reck_api-svbO_hqN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/bilal/.local/share/virtualenvs/face_reck_api-svbO_hqN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/bilal/.local/share/virtualenvs/face_reck_api-svbO_hqN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/bilal/.local/share/virtualenvs/face_reck_api-svbO_hqN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/bilal/.local/share/virtualenvs/face_reck_api-svbO_hqN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/bilal/.local/share/virtualenvs/face_reck_api-svbO_hqN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/bilal/.local/share/virtualenvs/face_reck_api-svbO_hqN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/bilal/.local/share/virtualenvs/face_reck_api-svbO_hqN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/bilal/.local/share/virtualenvs/face_reck_api-svbO_hqN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/bilal/Desktop/Python/face_reck_api/app.py", line 74, in someting
    first_image_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(first_image)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I do not have enough reputation to comment, I will add this here

1. Please add error message you are getting
2. From the [Flask Documentation](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/178#issuecomment-330004009), "*Note that files will only contain data if the request method was POST, PUT or PATCH and the  that posted to the request had enctype="multipart/form-data". It will be empty otherwise.*"

From what I can garner from the above code snippet you seem to be missing a request method of POST,PUT, OR PATCH

## Update

Please take a look at this it seems, that  If no face is found in the image, the encodings array will be empty. So check the length of the array before you try to access the first element (i.e. element [0]) of the array.

For example:

```
encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)
if len(encodings) > 0:
    biden_encoding = encodings[0]
else:
   print("No faces found in the image!")
   quit()
```

``
[Github link to similar issue](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/178#issuecomment-330004009)

Comment: Thank You, but the problem isn't in the POST request, it is in the image processing.

Comment: Could you clarify which function seems to be failing?
1.   first_image = face_recognition.load_image_file('./img/mj.png')
2.    first_image_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(first_image)[0]

From your stack trace it seems No.2 is where the fail is happening, however your initial comment seems to say No.1 is where you believe is its failing at?
I ask this because I am unable to run face_recognition on my end to test it out myself @BiloSuper